# Flow type action does work with Object refrerence

Tags: javascript, react-redux, flowtype

Why does flow throw an error using an object as Reference here:

```
type LoadUserData = { type: actionTypes.LOAD_USER_DATA, user: User };
```

But when a string is used no error is thrown:

```
type LoadUserData = { type: "LOAD_USER_DATA", user: User };
```

The error that is thrown is:

```
Error:(8, 29) Flow: string. Ineligible value used in/as type annotation (did you forget 'typeof'?) LOAD_USER_DATA
```

Comment: Here is the relevant Flow issue: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2377 I'm afraid you won't find the conclusion there very satisfactory.

Comment: @JordanRunning - was hoping that wasn't the case. Thank you for the link to that issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeof` as it suggests, but that probably won't do what you want:

```
const actionTypes = {
  LOAD_USER_DATA: 'foo'
}

type LoadUserData = { type: typeof actionTypes.LOAD_USER_DATA};

({type: 'bar'}: LoadUserData) // no errors
```

This happens because Flow infers the type of `actionTypes.LOAD_USER_DATA` to be `string`.

Unfortunately for your use case you will probably have to just write out the string literals again in the type.

Comment: Yea - Flow is awesome but looks like it has some kinks to work out.

Comment: @m_callens did you read my answer? That is exactly what I said.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `Flow` doesn't allow you to use constants within your type definitions. It must either be a data type or a constant *value*, but no variables. Therefore, you'll have to stick with the:

```
type LoadUserData = { type: 'LOAD_USER_DATA', user: User }
```

I'm assuming this is a type definition for a `Redux` action, in which case, Facebook's [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/frameworks/redux/) actually recommend this anyway!