# Disjoint Union types based on object property literal type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am trying to properly type an object whose definition changes based on the value of one of its properties. Using constants for `type` below works fine (ie: replacing `type: typeA` with `type: 1` fixes the error), but for clarity in the code base, I would like to use constants imported from a shared `constants.js`. Why is flow unhappy about this?

```
const typeA = 1;
const typeB = 2;

type pA = {
  type: typeA,
    //  ^ Cannot use number as a type because number is a value. To get the type of a value use `typeof`.
  vA: string,
};

type pB = {
  type: typeB,
  vB: string,
};

type p = pA | pB;

const getV = (proj): string => {
    switch (proj.type) {
      case typeA: {
        return proj.vA;
      }
      case typeB: {
        return proj.vB;
      }
    }
  return '';
}
```

[try it](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzAEEwBeMARgG5McCwAhMsAJhtXwE8AHAUzG4lyAb1RgwXPgC5iAGjFgAbkRkEATgEtsAc3kBfdpP7cmIhUZkN54xQ1X5NO-YZ7HmgsAB8BDdljyE2rz4AGrMABTcanAAVgCU9o7aZAB8YKIAkLgIGvgYABZgkdExAHRGcekK4uIYAIa4-CpVNa1gasEArmrYAiWlyjRtYHrVNfWNjDKiw+Id+N29UbEDvmPio62b7V09YADk+zSjqEA)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use external constant when defining flow literal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834435/use-external-constant-when-defining-flow-literal-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare A and B as types, and then switch using `typeof`

```
/* @flow */

type A = 1;
type B = 2;

type pA = {
  type: A,
  vA: string,
};

type pB = {
  type: B,
  vB: string,
};

type p = pA | pB;

const getV = (proj): string => {
    switch (proj.typeof) {
      case "A": {
        return proj.vA;
      }
      case "B": {
        return proj.vB;
      }
    }
  return '';
}
```

Comment: Wow, this looks really weird. It works on this, but I think I'm having another problem in my actual codebase. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `proj.typeof` is not defined on the type of `p`; also, it should be casing on `1` and `2` and not on `"A"` or `"B"`.